# Uninstall WxWidgets made from .sln file

Tags: visual-studio, wxwidgets, sln-file

I had installed WxWidgets using this video tutorial : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOIbK4bJKS8)

I now need to uninstall it properly so I am concerned that if I just directly delete the entire folder created for WxWidgets and then remove from system variables will be fine or should I do something else

Update:
I forgot to mention that I am running Windows

Comment: Are you trying to remove wxWidgets from your project or uninstall it completely from your operating system?

Comment: uninstall it completely from my system

Comment: @sidewala, just delete the folder and the env. variable. If you want - you can remove it from the `Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall...`, but I'm sure it will just do the same thing. The library by itself doesn't create any registry keys...

Comment: @Igor there actually no option to uninstall from Control Panel that is why I asked if I should delete the folder and env variable

Comment: @sidewala, that's proves my point - wxWidgets by itself doesn't modify the registry... ;-) Just delete the folder and env vars.